# below code results in vertical reverse text in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
svg.append('rect')
                        .attr('width',"150%")
                        .attr('height',"130%")
                        .attr('x', '10%')
                        .attr('y', '100%')
                        .style('fill','white')
                    svg.append('text')
                        .style("fill", "black")
                        .style("font-size", "356px")
                        .attr("dy", ".35em")
                        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate(0)")
                        .text('min')
```

above code results in [image] but i need in "min" this way please help me out !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seemed to have a transform on svg that you need to cancel out. Change your transform attribute in the above code to

```
 ...
 .attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate(0) scale(1,-1)")
 ...
```